# Adding a JInternalFrame in Java doesn´t work

Tags: java, jframe, jinternalframe, jdesktoppane

I have tried in many ways to add an internal frame to my existing one. I have tried with and without JPanel.  But nothing worked and I don´t have a clue why. Anyone?

```
public class Menu_new extends JFrame{


private BufferedImage background = null;


public Menu_new() {

    try {
        background = ImageIO.read(new File("pics_1/hallo.jpg"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JDesktopPane desktop = new JDesktopPane();
    JInternalFrame inside = new JInternalFrame(("Data"), true, true, true, true);
    desktop.add(inside);



    inside.setBounds(50, 50, 300, 500);
    inside.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    inside.setVisible(true);
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Your name");
    inside.add(label);

    JTextField text = new JTextField(10);
    inside.add(text);
    Icon icon = new ImageIcon("pics_1/Button.png");
    JButton start = new JButton(icon);
    start.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());

    inside.add(start);

    inside.moveToFront();
    this.add(desktop);
 }


 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, this);
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method of adding the components to the internal frame is wrong.

The default layout manager (for internal frame as well as for JFrame) is `BorderLayout` and therefore requires that you specify where you want to place your components. (As a special case if you only add a single component it seems to work without specifying a constraint).

Your code to add the components should look like this:

```
inside.add(label, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
...
inside.add(text, BorderLayout.CENTER);
...
inside.add(start, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```

---

As an additional note, this `inside.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` has no effect, since `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE` is not valid for internal frames.

Comment: @user3612671 please consider accepting the answer if this has helped